# Is the following distribution a form of another well-known one?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In my research, I derived the following distribution. However, it does not seem to resemble the form of any well-known distributions. I wanted to see if anyone is seeing something I am not or if I am probably correct.

Thanks for taking a look!

\begin{equation}
p(X=x)
 = \left(1-e^{-x^2/2}\right)
   e^{-x+\mathrm{erf}\left(x/\sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{\pi/2}}
   I_{[0,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation}

Comment: You'll need to change $\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-1\right)$ to $\left(1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)$ to make your density positive.

Comment: Silly oversight. Thank you